# Start chrome and get its process id

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a batch script that opens chrome in new window with an url address, then return its ProcessId.
I've tried with other applications like notepad , it works fine but with chrome it always returns ProcessId = 0

ProcessId: 28388
(notepad is opened with specified file)

```
@echo off
set pid=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in ('wmic process call create "notepad.exe Dummy.txt"^,"%~dp0." ^| find "ProcessId"') do set pid=%%a
echo ProcessId: %pid%
pause>nul
```

ProcessId: 0
(nothing happens then)

```
    @echo off
set pid=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in ('wmic process call create "chrome.exe https://www.google.com"^,"%~dp0." ^| find "ProcessId"') do set pid=%%a
echo ProcessId: %pid%
pause>nul
```

Any solution for this ? thank you in advance

Comment: Let me guess: is there a `%`-sign in the URL? if so, double it…

Comment: @aschipfl yes, i did but even simple url like  https://www.google.com it doesn't

Comment: I believe that the create process no longer returns a process id.  I am not sure when it was changed in Windows.

Comment: @RohitGupta you mean what application ? create process still returns ProcessId with notepad

Comment: Please [edit] your question code to provide the exact and reproducible command content which is failing for you. It is no good showing us a fully working code example, then just expecting us to recreate your exact problem by guessing the failing command arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise that you use the following template which uses more robust syntax:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "Exec=%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
Set "Args=https://www.google.com"
Set "WDir=%~dp0."

Set "ProcessId="
For /F "Delims=;" %%G In ('^"%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Process Call
 Create '"%Exec%" "%Args%"'^,'%WDir%' 2^>NUL
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "\<ProcessId\>"^"') Do Set /A %%G

(Set ProcessId) 2>NUL
Pause
```

*Obviously the bottom two lines are included just to show you the successful variable name and value.*

Please replace only the strings between the `=` and closing doublequote on lines `4`, `5` and `6`, as necessary. Please ensure that those strings themselves do not include doublequotes, or end with trailing backward slashes.

Comment: Thank you @Compo ! Your code runs fine, but the PID doesn't match.

Comment: It returns 1512  while it was actually 14828 when i checked task manager in Chrome. I've searched a lot but it's really hard because chrome generates many PIDs .
I'm thinking about getting the PIDs before and after opening a new tab, then filtering out the PIDs as utility , extension to find the new tab's PID .. Oh, many things to do, so miserable with batch

Comment: There is absolutely no way that CreateProcess is returning the wrong process identifier. Please, insert the following two lines, before the `Pause` line: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 10 /NoBreak 1>NUL``` then either: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Process Where "ProcessId='%ProcessId%'" Call Terminate```, or: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /F /PId %ProcessId% /T```. It should terminate/kill the process you created, and therefore your assertion that it is outputting the wrong process identifier is incorrect. I actually use this methodology myself, and it always works.

Comment: Still have no luck . An error : no instances are available. 
I've realized that your code works perfectly only when no instances of Chrome is running. If Chrome is already opened it will get error. And the ProcessId which it returns is not tab's ProcessId. It is  ProcessId of "browser " in Chrome task manager.

Comment: You are correct, however none of those things formed any part of your question, and are therefore irrelevant to my answer. If you wanted your question to be about opening a new tab in an existing chrome parent process, then you should have done so, however I have provided robust code to return the ProcessId as requested. Out of curiosity, as I would never put that application on any machine, _not even on customer request_, what happens if you use the `--new-window` option in your command `Args`.

Comment: Actually i want to track chrome's tab processid to know when the user turns it off. At first I thought it was easy but it has many case scenarios that need to be covered. 
--new-window didn't make any changes . As i said it doesn't work if chrome is already launched. With your code, the only way to do is force user close chrome before opening bat file,and i'm thinking about that. I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some ideas.

Comment: I have answered the question you asked in your question. Your reported issue was that the same command used with your notepad example was not returning the ProcessId with chrome. My answer addresses that, and always captures the returned ProcessId for both and without issue. If you want an answer to your new, and completely different issue, you should consider asking that as a new question, on an appropriate platform. In the meantime, as you have agreed that my code above does indeed capture the returned ProcessId, you should consider marking it as accepted, so that future readers can benefit.